# Several Instances of 'styled-components' initialized in this application

Tags: reactjs, typescript, gatsby, styled-components

I've tried all the solutions and now have come to ask this question , I am building a ui component library.

I have two packages , one for library , one for demo , The demo makes use of library using a symlink , file:../ui in its package.json , I build the library first and then consume it in the demo package

The code is available at https://github.com/Qawaz/qal-ui/

I've tried deduping dependencies using `npm dedupe` but it didn't work. Upon using command `npm ls styled-components` I get

```
+-- @paljs/ui@1.1.1 -> .\..\ui
| `-- styled-components@6.0.3
+-- babel-plugin-styled-components@2.1.4
| `-- styled-components@6.0.3 deduped
+-- gatsby-plugin-styled-components@6.11.0
| `-- styled-components@6.0.3 deduped
`-- styled-components@6.0.3
```

Previously I had parent module and workspaces enabled and the two packages were sharing dependencies using npm but I removed that , I migrated to completely separate modules but one module makes a dependency on the other using symlink.

- styled-components is a peer dependency in the component library not direct
- version of styled-components is consistent across both projects
- gatsby is being used , babel plugin for styled components & gatsby plugin for styled components are being used

After adding this to my `gatsby-node.js` , which is suggested in some answers

```
const path = require("path")
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({stage, actions}) => {
    actions.setWebpackConfig({
        resolve: {
            alias: {
                "styled-components": path.resolve("node_modules", "styled-components"),
            }
        }
    })
}
```

I get this error in the console , This error is a false-negative , It goes away if you change something in your `gatsby-config` and appears at random times

```
export 'createContentDigest' (imported as 'createContentDigest') was not found in 'gatsby-core-utils/create-content-digest' (module has no exports)
```

Some answers also suggest this , It causes my build to break

```
optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: {
        name: "vendor"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that `styled-components` just starts complaining if you are using a library with components which also uses `styled-components` because multiple instances.
So I switched to `emotion`, I keep `emotion` in peer dependencies and the experience is much better, Since `emotion` contains most features of `styled-components` and API is very similar.
There's also `goober` which provides a setup method, which can be called by the library consumer, `goober` is a fantastic choice but when I tried to use goober, It didn't contain `useTheme` hook plus `goober` is very focused on keeping the bundle smaller while delivering features of css in js.